# Posting to the FB Wall with fb_graph2 Gem is not pulling OG information

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, fb-graph

I am having an issue here.  So I have a rails application that is using the fb_graph2 gem.  My application allows users to share an article from my application to their facebook wall.  I have created a landing URL for my application that tracks the click ( for metrics on my application ) and then redirects the user to the original article.

I run my tracking URL through the FB Linter and it pulls all my data correctly but when I post to from the my application it does not pull any OG data.  If I paste the tracking URL into FB it pulls the data.  But when coming from my app, it get the image that is below.  You can test the url from my dev server using my dev app.
https://raydodev.herokuapp.com/api/v2/common/articles/metrics/track/1203

[how my data shows up on facebook when posting from my rails app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKcHS.png)

Using the FB Graph i am posting with the code below:

```
me = FbGraph2::User.me(user.fbaccesstoken)
msg = {
  message:'foo',
  picture: 'https://bar.png',
  link: 'http://foobar/page.html',
  name: 'This is the article title',
  description: 'This is the article description'
}
me.feed!(msg)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated